# WordPress Other post categories redirect to primary category

Tags: wordpress, seo, permalinks

I have posts with *n* categories, but one is primary.

Example categories: test(primary), test1, test2, test3

One post has *n* links for each other categories. This is bad for SEO. The example below:

- www.domain.net/test/post-name
- www.domain.net/test1/post-name
- etc.

I want the post to be displayed only in the link with the primary category.

www.domain.net/test/post-name

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

## Technically

... you could add something like

```
RewriteRule ^test1/(.*)$ /test/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

to your .htaccess file (I'm not an server expert) to redirect the category folders. But this will always redirect all those categories to the primary one. I guess, it's not what you're looking for.

## But, from an SEO perspective

... you should think about using only one category per post, to enhance the structure of your website.

Often categories are used like tags, so if you now have categories like cooking, fish, potatoes and fast-food, the last three maybe should be better tags and only cooking the one and only category.

Also if a category is a parent of another category of the post, it shouldn't be used, too.